# Python task threads receiving duplicate arguments

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded Python program, in which I am firing off worker threads to process a list of input data. The data they process then requires network operations, which effectively makes them I/O bound (so the GIL isn't a problem for me).

I'm getting an issue where multiple worker threads are apparently receiving the same input, but I can't figure out why. As far as I can tell, I'm not sharing any thread-unsafe data between threads.

I've created a minimized version of what I'm trying to do. This program exhibits the problem without doing any of the I/O or anything:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(threadName)-10s %(levelname)-7s %(message)s")

sema = threading.Semaphore(10)

# keep track of already-visited data in worker threads
seen = []
seenlock = threading.Lock()

def see(num):
    try:
        logging.info("see: look at %d", num)

        with seenlock:
            if num in seen:
                # this should be unreachable if each thread processes a unique number
                logging.error("see: already saw %d", num)
            else:
                seen.append(num)

        time.sleep(0.3)

    finally:
        sema.release()


def main():
    # start at 1, so that the input number matches the log's "Thread-#"
    for i in xrange(1, 100):
        sema.acquire() # prevent more than 10 simultaneous threads
        logging.info("process %d", i)
        threading.Thread(target=lambda: see(i)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

And some of the output:

```
MainThread INFO    process 1
MainThread INFO    process 2
Thread-1   INFO    see: look at 2
Thread-2   INFO    see: look at 2
MainThread INFO    process 3
Thread-2   ERROR   see: already saw 2
MainThread INFO    process 4
Thread-3   INFO    see: look at 4
Thread-4   INFO    see: look at 4
MainThread INFO    process 5
Thread-4   ERROR   see: already saw 4
Thread-5   INFO    see: look at 5
MainThread INFO    process 6
Thread-6   INFO    see: look at 6
MainThread INFO    process 7
Thread-7   INFO    see: look at 7
MainThread INFO    process 8
Thread-8   INFO    see: look at 8
MainThread INFO    process 9
MainThread INFO    process 10
```

The only possibly weird thing that I feel I am doing is to acquire a semaphore permit on a thread other than where it gets released, but semaphores should be thread-safe and unconcerned with who acquires and releases the permits, as long as there are the same number of each.

Confirmed on:

- Python 2.7.3 (Windows; build from python.org)
- Python 2.6.7 (Windows; cygwin dist)
- Python 2.6.6 (Linux; Debian dist)

What am I doing to cause my threads to share data?

Comment: You should really use a Queue() to pipe the data to your threads. That way you don't need to concern yourself with writing all this "seen"/"unseen" code.

Comment: I've only added the "seen"/"unseen" code for the sake of debugging. When I noticed my program was processing the same things repeatedly (and missing other things), I made the threads track what they were doing. Good tip about Queue, though.

Comment: Thanks. Using `Queue()` would ensure that no thread ever processes data that has already been processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threading. It has to do with the behavior of closures.

```
>>> funcs = []
>>> for x in range(10):
...     def foo():
...         return x
...     funcs.append(foo)
... 
>>> [f() for f in funcs]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

When you define a function and refer to a variable in the enclosing scope, the value of that variable is *always* the value of that variable *in the enclosing scope, at the time of function invocation*. Since these functions are all invoked after the end of the `for` loop, `x == 9` for all 10 invocations.

A simple way to fix the problem is to use a default value. In short, change this:

```
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: see(i)).start()
```

To this:

```
    threading.Thread(target=lambda x=i: see(x)).start()
```

Or, better yet, use the full power of the `Thread` constructor (thanks to Joel Cornett for reminding me):

```
    threading.Thread(target=see, args=(i,)).start()
```

Comment: To add to your answer, another way of solving this problem would be to create the Thread object like this: `threading.Thread(target=see, args=(1,)).start()`

Comment: @JoelCornett, you're right, that's the better approach. Thanks.